# How do I return timestamp instead of time from influxdb?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

I query data from InfluxDB 2 using Flux query like:

```
from(bucket: "first")
  |> range(start: time(v: 0))
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_measurement"] == "test" and r._field == "volume")
  |> keep(columns: ["_time", "_value"])
  |> last()
```

This gives me a correct result, but it gives me the `_time` column as a human-readable date.
I need a timestamp instead. Seconds, milliseconds, nanoseconds, doesn't matter.

I tried adding `|> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with timestamp: uint(v: r._time) }))` before `keep(...` and modifying `keep(...` to keep the new field. And this still works correctly, but it **significantly** increases the response time (and this is understandable, why).

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing this wrong, so how do I do this?

updated: I managed not to increase the response time. I moved `|> map` below `last()`, but I still think this is not the best way of doing this.

Comment: Exactly what I was searching for. Your solution works but do let me know if you found "the best way". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an accurate timestamp and format is not relevant, then use string instead of uint for better response time-

```
|> map(fn: (r) => ({ r with timestamp: string(v: r._time) }))
ex output with nanosecond precision- 2023-01-01T01:50:25.663017890Z
```

I don't know your use case, but this is probably the best way to get the actual timestamp stored by influxdb.